# How to dynamically select into query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

```
EXECUTE format(
'SELECT MAX(sum) 
FROM  table 1
WHERE %s    =   %s') INTO max_value USING id_column, id_value;
```

> Getting error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying =
>   integer.

Also, when I try to run the below code:

```
update table1 set column2 = max_value + sum;
```

I get another error:

> "ERROR:  column "max_value" does not exist"

Comment: Please show us your **complete** function. For the first part of the question: You should use `%I` as a placeholder for a column name and `%L` for the value.

Comment: At glance – you need to add format() parameter values inside format() itself not outside (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT). Secondly, your update using variable `max_value` is probably dealing with the first problem – this variable is never assigned a value from dynamic SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION maxvaloftable ()
 RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$

   DECLARE

resultat integer = 2;

BEGIN

resultat= (SELECT MAX(sum) FROM  table) ;

RETURN resultat;
END;
$BODY$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE STRICT
    COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION maxvaloftable()
 OWNER TO postgres;

update table1 set column2 = (select  maxvaloftable ()) + sum;
```